# How can python find decorated functions within it?

Tags: python, design-patterns, flask, python-decorators

In the following code how does app.run() find that hello() exists? I browsed the code and couldn't find the answer. I think the hello() doesn't get added to a list of routes until it is called, but how does it get called?

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I'm not interested in Flask in particular. I'd just like to implement something similar myself.

What is this design pattern called?

Comment: Please see the define of the `route` function https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L1224

Comment: read this [_short_ intro on decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/7505395)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. Decorators are themselves executable code, and they are called when the function they decorate is *defined*, ie at import time. The code within the decorator can then add the route to its registry.